# Add year drop down to dijit calendar

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to add a year drop down similar to the month drop down in dojo. I managed to create the regular calendar but I am stumped when it comes to adding the year drop down.

Can you guys provide some heads up.

Answer (score 0):

instead of a calendar i sugest to use a number spinner with a range.

regards.